# MySQL Migration Toolkit & SQL Express

Tags: mysql, sql-server-express

I'm trying to port a database from SQL Server Express over to my MySQL database.  I've made sure the SQL Express is running on port 1433 and all, and the MySQL Migration toolkit is even able to see the different databases/schemas I have in my SQL Server Express DB.

The problem is that MySql Migration toolkit won't let me press "next" until I enter a username/password, which doesn't make sense to me since it is able to connect to the Express DB and view all of the schemas without those.

I've tried using the "advanced" settings to directly specify the connection string, but that's not working for me either.  I'm probably getting the string wrong.  Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahah!  I got it!  I was able to make it work using this connection string:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/Bookstore;user=;password=;charset=utf-8;domain=
```

I put that in the advanced text box, and then just a space for the username (that probably could have been anything though).

(The sa and empty password trick wouldn't work for me)

Answer (score 1):

OK. In Source Database select MS SQL Server. In Advanced Settings write

jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.210.4.2:1433/INFRASTRUCTURE;instance=MENG;user=sa;password=XXX;charset=utf-8;domain=

Test your connection with clic button database to retrive list from server. 
If no conect then:

- ¿Do you connected from remote machine? OK is your firewall Up? Can shutdown? No? configure and open your 1433 port or SqlServer executable.

Ah! and enable and Start SqlServer Browser service!

Uhhh fill the other text box to activate the next button.

Happy MySqling!

Answer (score 1):

For any other poor soul trying to get this work, try this. Enabling TCP/IP connections for SQL express seems to do the trick.

http://www.pierrebuckley.com/2010/06/02/resolving-connection-error-with-mysql-migration-toolkit/

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL Express has access for user 'sa' and empty password. Try that.